# SourceTree: Why aren't branches showing as merged?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Can you help me understand - after merging 'release/1.0.0' into 'master' why they dont show as merged in the SourceTree graph?

I did the merge via a Pull Request using Microsoft DevOps

Then checked out 'master' locally and did a Pull - this is what the graph shows now:

[image: SourceTree Branch graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four ways to "merge" a pr on DevOps, according to the documentation:

> - **Merge (no fast forward)**: Merge with a non-linear history that preserves all commits.
> - **Squash commit**: Merge with a linear history that combines all source commits into a single commit on the target, or squash merges the PR.
> - **Rebase and fast-forward**: Rebase the source commits onto the target and fast-forward.
> - **Semi-linear merge**: Rebase source commits onto the target and create a two-parent merge.

Only two of those (with "merge" in their name) make a merge commit. You probably did one of the others. My guess is that you did a squash.

Comment: Yes, I did do a Squash commit. So by creating that single new commit, we don't see the graph 'merge' the lines?

Comment: Right. That's what a squash is. When you asked for that, you were saying you wanted _not_ to have the graph merge the lines. You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/